# How to hide css offset-path property in safari? CSS supports rule doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, css-animations

CSS motion path isn't supported in safari. I've tried using CSS supports rule to target offset-path but it isn't working.

```js
if (CSS.supports("offset-path", "M0.5 1H1549.5")) {
   console.log("supported yay");
   // Motion path is not supported, apply fallback styles or alternative actions
   //   element.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
} else {
   console.log("not supported");
}
```

I try this logic and it doesn't work in chromium browsers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium browsers [*do*](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_offset-path_path-support) support `offset-path` property with `path()` values.

But `CSS.supports()` requires the correct value syntax and otherwise, it'll return false. There's no in-between, i.e. a result that says **"It supports the value but the syntax is incorrect"**.

So, just use the correct value like this:

```
if (CSS.supports("offset-path", `path("M0.5 1H1549.5")`)) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports_static) has to be a valid value. Did you perhaps forget to wrap your value in `path`?

```js
// Returns false, the value is not a valid value
console.log(CSS.supports("offset-path", "M0.5 1H1549.5"));

// Returns true on Chromium browsers
console.log(CSS.supports("offset-path", "path('M0.5 1H1549.5')"));
```